# Symfony Exception - An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Entity was not found.")

Tags: exception, symfony, doctrine

This happens because there is an ID in table A and when mapping into table B it cannot find the record because it simply does not exist.

My question is:

Is there anyway where we can catch this **Exception** in symfony so that I can use a try catch block to handle this error?

> Framework: Symfony
>
> Exception: EntityNotFoundException: Entity was not found

Comment: Pardon... I don't have enough reputation yet to post a comment. Can you post your Doctrine mappings and the relevant entity code? It'll be difficult to diagnose the issue otherwise.